# I am looking to split up multiple lines of text and place them in textboxes in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, split

I was developing a antimalware, and wanted to read Signature from a Signature.txt file, and place all the strings into different textboxes, my viruslist has 90069500 malware **(Took Almost A Year Collecting Them)** signatures and if I start typing then like:

```
If buff.ToString = "000008298FC27014ECF5610F163277E2" Then
            txtvirname.Text = "Trojan-GameThief.Win32.OnLineGames.tvl"
            txtrisk.Text = "Moderate"
            txtrisk.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
            txtfinger.Text = "Delete :: Permanently""
```

Is there any way to find the MD5 Hash (Like: "000008298FC27014ECF5610F163277E2") in the list's lines and then split that line and place the hash, name, Preferred action and risk into separate textboxes

Comment: can you post what a line in that file looks like? I guess you can use regular expressions to parse each line. But is hard to say which one to use without knowing what to parse

Comment: First question is what do the entries in the text file look like

Comment: A text file is a very poor substitute for a database.  A hundred million entries is *way* beyond practical.

Comment: @Hans in which case he needs to do an ETL excercise that will require him to parse the contents of the text file... and that would apper to be where we came in

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks for your complement, I just forgot to place them, but they look something like this:                                              <code>000000B4DCCFBAA5BD981AF2C1BBF59A;3;Trojan-GameThief.Win32.OnLineGames.ikb
000001476E5B3B637B7BFAE6C18F5F5E;3;Trojan-GameThief.Win32.OnLineGames.mcv
000008298FC27014ECF5610F163277E2;3;Trojan-GameThief.Win32.OnLineGames.tvl
000010A2299064694E98676A776D4CBD;3;Trojan-GameThief.Win32.OnLineGames.twc<code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make all the lines the same length, then it is posssible to calculate the starting position of each line. Order the lines by the hash, then you can make a binary search in the file without loading it. Use the `Seek` method of the `FileStream` class in order to read at random positions in the file.

**EDIT**:
Assuming that 100 bytes are used to store one line, this code accesses a specific line:

```
Public Function GetLine(lineNo As Integer, stream As FileStream) As String
    Const  LineLength As Integer = 100 ' Including CR/LF
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(LineLength-1);

    stream.Seek(lineNo * LineLength, SeekOrigin.Begin) ' Line number assumed zero based.
    Dim bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, LineLength)
    ' For simplicity, I assume that the file is ASCII encoded, other encodings might
    ' use two bytes per character or even a variable length.
    Return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
End Function
```

See here for the [Binary Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: Sie I can't understand, can you be a more clear and give some code examples?